# Standard way of making specific shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration

[image]Hello. I am beginner in Adobe illustrator. Can anyone guide that how can I make this shape in standard way without using pen tool.

Comment: [Unicode 1D197](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d197/index.htm) - No Pen tool, just a font that supports the Unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

You seemingly have noticed to prevent bitmap tracing by giving a blurry image. But no pen! Disabling the most efficient drawing tool makes the job slow.  But there's still enough tools left.

[image]

1. Draw a circle and a line
2. insert an anchor point to the middle of the line by applying Object > Path > Add anchor points. Drag the anchors to better positions with the direct selection tool
3. Change the anchors smooth with the anchor type tool. You can also draw the handle directions at the same time like with the pen, but that happens now without the pen. Move the anchors more with the direct selection tools and adjust the handles.
4. Make the path width non.uniform with the Width tool
5. Apply to the hook Object > Path > Outline Stroke. Unite the circle and the hook to one filled shape with Pathfinder panel Unite
6. Refine the joint with the direct selection tool. Move anchors and adjust handles. Remove unnecessary anchors if that's allowed (the removal tool resembles the Pen maybe too much)
7. Make a duplicate, rotate it 180 degrees  with Object > Transform > Rotate. Place it and unite the halves.
8. Apply Object > Path > Simplify for generally smoother appearance.

Another possibility is to type a character with a font which contains the wanted shape. I unfortunately do not know if some font has it.

Comment: Done. Thank you

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAmin if it helped you can click the accept answer button.